# How to access the inner array resulting from d3.groups?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling to understand how I can use the new [d3.group and d3.groups methods](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group). My goal is to add a dropdown menu to my d3.chart. Specifically, when I select an option, the chart displays the data for this particular individual. My problem is that I don't understand how I can access the inner array for the selected individual. For example, if I select bib nr. 5, I want to access this individual's ratio score.

I have been stuck for this problem for a long time. I appreciate your help :)

```js
const data = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
  bib: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
  ratio: -1 + Math.random() * 5,
  run: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
  name: ['GIRL1', 'GIRL2', 'GIRL3', 'GIRL4'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
}));

// Now I want to use d3.groups
const skiers = d3.groups(data, d => d.bib)

//Logging this gives me a nested array.
console.log(skiers)

// I want to access the inner array for a particular individual, but how can I accomplish this?
// I have tried to use .map()
console.log(skiers.map(d => d.run)) //This gives me undefines
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@6.2.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all the objects where `d[0]` equals the `bib` you're trying to collect;

```js
const data = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
  bib: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
  ratio: -1 + Math.random() * 5,
  run: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
  name: ['GIRL1', 'GIRL2', 'GIRL3', 'GIRL4'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
}));

const skiers = d3.groups(data, d => d.bib)

const bibToFind = 3;

// Array with objects
const bibFound = skiers.filter(d => d[0] === bibToFind);

// Objects only
const bibObjects = bibFound[0][1];

console.log(bibFound, bibObjects);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@6.2.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whe you use `.map` you're iterating only the first level of nested array

```js
[
  [ // "d" is this array in your map function 
    1,
    [
      {
        "bib": 1,
        "ratio": 0.6494187230703661,
        "run": 1,
        "name": "GIRL1"
      },
      {
        "bib": 1,
        "ratio": -0.2740398059491158,
        "run": 2,
        "name": "GIRL1"
      },
      {
        "bib": 1,
        "ratio": 3.3705616486650136,
        "run": 3,
        "name": "GIRL1"
      },
      {
        "bib": 1,
        "ratio": 0.9649181479003297,
        "run": 4,
        "name": "GIRL1"
      },
      {
        "bib": 1,
        "ratio": 1.7259011213023032,
        "run": 5,
        "name": "GIRL1"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

```js
const data = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
  bib: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
  ratio: -1 + Math.random() * 5,
  run: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
  name: ['GIRL1', 'GIRL2', 'GIRL3', 'GIRL4'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
}));

// Now I want to use d3.groups
const skiers = d3.groups(data, d => d.bib)

//Logging this gives me a nested array.
console.log(skiers[0]) // first level
console.log(skiers[0][1]) // second level take second element
console.log(skiers[0][1][0]) // here you have the first object

// so you can map over the specific level of the nested array 
console.log(skiers[0][1].map(d => d.run)) // no mo undefined

//or you can convert the nested array to a simple array if if that what are you looking
console.log("flatmap",skiers.flatMap(d=> d[1])) 
// and the acces each run property
console.log("flatmap",skiers.flatMap(d=> d[1]).map(d => d.run))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@6.2.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I think I understand it :) And if I want to filter a specific bib, then I can use @0stone0 's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `d3.group` and `d3.groups` is that the former returns a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), while the latter returns an array. Therefore, if you use `d3.group`, the only thing you'll need to get the array (say `bib` 1) is:

```
skiers.get(1);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const data = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
  bib: Math.floor(i / 5) + 1,
  ratio: -1 + Math.random() * 5,
  run: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i % 5],
  name: ['GIRL1', 'GIRL2', 'GIRL3', 'GIRL4'][Math.floor(i / 5)]
}));

// Now I want to use d3.groups
const skiers = d3.group(data, d => d.bib)

const innerArray = skiers.get(1);

console.log(innerArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@6.2.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cheers. Can I input a Map directly to a d3 selection or do I need to convert it to an array?

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen if you mean `selection.data()`, yes, you can.